# How to reference all the rows except the first one using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` element containing a table. I need to set the height of all the rows except the first one to a fixed number. Also I need to set a text inside of all columns to a particular size except of first row:

This is an `html` I have:

```
<style>
    #divFileSet
    {
        border:0px solid gray;  
        position:absolute; 
        top:170px; 
        left:170px; 
        overflow:visible;width:1020px;height:450px; 

    }
</style>
```

This is html section:

```
<div id="divFileSet" >
    <table cellspacing ="3px";  cellpadding="3px" style="border:1px solid gray;">
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2" style="font-size:large; color:white; background-color:#005482;">
            <span>File Status:</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="...">Session 1</a></td><br/>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="..."> Session 2</a></td><br/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="...">Session 3</a></td><br />
         </tr>            
    </table>
    </div>
```

The `html` generates something like this:

[image]

I need to set height and text for the 2 - 4 row.

How can I do it using `css`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:not(:first-child)`

```
div table tr:not(:first-child) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An even IE7 compatible version would be:

```
tr + tr {
    /* styles */
}
```

But of course this one is not really beautiful.